# Selecting a single object from a thymeleaf table and passing it back to a controller via thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a table of objects in thymeleaf with join buttons beside each objects data, im wondering is it possible to have it so when the user clicks "join" beside the row they desire it will send the selected object to the controller.

Here is what I have for it but I know it is not correct as I am getting a null pointer exception in my controller.

```
th:each="team : ${teams}"
 th:text="${team.teamName}"
 th:text="${team.teamAddress}"
 th:text="${team.level}"
     th:text="${team.manager}"></td>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">View Team</button>  

         th:action="@{/jointeam}" method="post" th:object="${team}"

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Join Team</button>
```

my controller code:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/jointeam", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public String joinTeam(@Valid Team team, Principal principal)
   {


//     String userName = (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getName();

       Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       String email = loggedInUser.getName();


       UserLogin user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

       team.addUserLogin(user);


               return "parseGame";
   }
```

Comment: You can't do that easily. But you can simply provide the id of the team and fetch it from your data store.

Comment: @BranislavLazic How would I go about passing the selected items ID using thymeleaf back to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, you can do it something like this:

```
th:each="team : ${teams}"
 th:text="${team.teamName}"
 th:text="${team.teamAddress}"
 th:text="${team.level}"
     th:text="${team.manager}"></td>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">View Team</button>  

         th:action="@{/jointeam/} + ${team.id}"

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Join Team</button>

@RequestMapping(value = "/jointeam/{teamId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String joinTeam(@PathVariable("team") Long teamId, Principal principal) {

   Team team = teamRepository.findOne(teamId); // Do whatever you want with team
   // String userName = (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getName();

   Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   String email = loggedInUser.getName();

   UserLogin user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

   team.addUserLogin(user);
   return "parseGame";
}
```

Notice that this is a GET call. You'd probably want to keep it as a POST call and create some ajax function that fires the `joinTeam` method.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the direction to use ajax, that seems to be what I should implement for what I am trying to do!